# Why isn't my tool script updating the size of my ColorRect nodes in the editor?

Tags: c#, godot

I am building a simple health bar using ColorRect nodes and I want to test that my script is working without running the project. I'm using a Tool script, however changing the values in the editor doesn't affect the size of the ColorRect. If I run the scene using F6 the script runs properly.

[image: Screenshot of the health bar scene in the Godot editor. Max Health is 100, Health is 50. The green health bar is still 100% of the width of the control.]

[image: Screenshot of the scene running. The green health bar is 50% of the width of the control.]

```cs
using Godot;

[Tool]
public class HealthBar : Control
{
  [Export]
  private float _maxHealth = 100;

  [Export]
  private float _health = 100;

  private ColorRect _backgroundRect;
  private ColorRect _healthRect;

  public override void _Ready()
  {
    base._Ready();
    _backgroundRect = this.GetExpectedNode<ColorRect>("Background");
    _healthRect = this.GetExpectedNode<ColorRect>("Health");

    if (_maxHealth < 1)
    {
      _maxHealth = 1;
    }
  }

  public override void _Process(float delta)
  {
    base._Process(delta);
    var maxWidth = _backgroundRect.RectSize.x;
    var healthPercentage = _health / _maxHealth;
    var healthWidth = maxWidth * healthPercentage;
    _healthRect.RectSize = new Vector2(healthWidth, _healthRect.RectSize.y);
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known bug with Tool scripts in Godot?

(Godot version: `3.5.1.stable.mono`)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I simply needed to close and re-open the tab and it's working now.